# Entity Framework, code first using fluent API, avoid inserting in referenced table

Tags: entity-framework, one-to-one

I have a table named **ServiceProviders** with static data. The POCO class is follows

```
public class ServiceProvider
    {
         public virtual int Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public virtual string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
 }
```

I have a **Client** table. Each client needs to have a reference to one of the "existing" service providers.

```
    public class Client
        {
         public virtual int Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }    

        public virtual string FirstName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public virtual string LastName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public virtual ServiceProvider ServiceProvider
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
}
```

I am configuring the client using EF code first fluent API as follows

```
public ClientConfiguration(): base()
        {
            HasKey(e => e.Id);
            Property(e => e.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            ToTable("dbo.Clients");
            Property(e => e.FirstName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(256).IsVariableLength().HasColumnType("nvarchar");
            Property(e => e.LastName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(256).IsVariableLength().HasColumnType("nvarchar");
            HasRequired(e => e.ServiceProvider).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("ServiceProviderId")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

When I want to insert a new client's record, I get a reference of an existing **ServiceProvider** instance and attach it to the Client's **ServiceProvider** property

```
Client client = new Client() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
client.ServiceProvider = serviceproviders[0]; //An existing ServiceProvider instance fetched from DB earlier
```

When I call SaveChanges, EF inserts a new (duplicate) record in my **ServiceProviders** table. All I want it to do is to insert a new record only in the **Client** Table and set the value of **ServiceProviderId** column to the existing ServiceProvider instance's **Id**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does serviceproviders come from the DbSet<ServiceProvider> ?

Comment: Yes, they do. I was disposing the context via which I was receiving the ServiceProvider instance. Attaching them back to the context solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach the existing `ServiceProvider` to the context you are saving the new `Client` in. `Attach` tells EF that the ServiceProvider already exists in the database and prevents an INSERT for that ServiceProvider:

```
Client client = new Client() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
context.ServiceProviders.Attach(serviceproviders[0]);
client.ServiceProvider = serviceproviders[0];
```